# scipy - interp2d - ValueError: When on a regular grid with x.size = m and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z must have shape (n, m)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

When I try to run the scipy intrap2d function, I'm getting an error with a rectangular data table.  I've got the initial x and y values using pandas pivot_table and am generating the z array.

ValueError: When on a regular grid with x.size = m and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z must have shape (n, m)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The scipy intrep2d init function checks for the x, y and z sizes.  If the table is a rectangular grid, it checks if the shape of z is equal to the shape of (len(y), len(x)).  If the shape of z isn't according to the x and y lengths, then it throws the error.

```
if rectangular_grid:
            if z.ndim == 2:
                if z.shape != (len(y), len(x)):
                    raise ValueError("When on a regular grid with x.size = m "
                                     "and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z "
                                     "must have shape (n, m)")
```

Reference: https://gemfury.com/stream/python:scipy/0.15.0/content/interpolate/interpolate.py

This error can be resolved by correcting the swaping the position of of x and y columns

In case of using Panda pivot_table

```
change 
df.pivot_table(values='z', index='x', columns='y')
TO
df.pivot_table(values='z', index='y', columns='x')
```

Alternately, you can update the z array and arrange it according to your x and y lengths.